# Is MKX region locked on PS4?

Tags: ps4, mortal-kombat-x

I've seen some articles ([like this](http://gamerant.com/mortal-kombat-x-region-lock/)) claiming that if you buy US version of MKX, you will not be able to play with EU friends, because game locks multiplayer for region of origin.

They also claim that executive producer Shaun Himmerick had a tweet at some point which confirmed this, but it's deleted now if ever existed.

Can someone confirm this information? Is US-EU online play possible in MKX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing online I can say from first-hand experience that there seems to be no region lock on online play in MKX. I studied profiles for the people met online and there is a mix of US and EU people there. My friend who plays this game shares the same experience.

EDIT: I'm from EU region and 99% of people I see online are from EU as well.  Even if there is no actual region-locking, it at least heavily uses region in matchmaking. But to play directly with a friend from another region seams possible (but I have no concrete info on this).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems so.

---

*[Url to now deleted tweet](https://twitter.com/lover_of_tacos/status/576513445538869248)*

[image]

Comment: The tweet seems to be real then, thanks. But it was deleted for some reason, so first-hand experience of region locking would be quite welcome.

Comment: Oh, right. it was deleted die to all he hate, I think. Um, after it gets released I will *try* to find something, no promise though.

Comment: @icebat Hm, I'm a little confused as to what this actually means then, as I played MK9 with an EU copy and I was successfully able to play online against a friend in Canada. I had no idea there was region-locking for MK9. However, my XBL profile is American, so I have no idea if that would have something to do with it?

Comment: @FAE, quite possibly the rules on PS and Xbox are different. But I remember trying Injustice on PS4 with a friend and it redirected us both to PS Store to buy the game instead of connecting us. I've seen some people reporting the same behavior when trying MKX on PS4 cross-region. I still don't have first-hand experience of this in MKX though.

Comment: Trying to find answer now, @icebat . For now, I found this;

> It (MKX team) is telling major reviewers to wait for the online to be proven to work well before scoring the game.

To continue; 
> Their caution was justified. The steam version of the game doesn't work. Any selection from the main menu results in the game crashing.

Answer (score 0):

No, Mortal Kombat X does [not allow cross region multiplier](http://shoryuken.com/2015/03/14/mortal-kombat-x-will-not-allow-cross-region-netplay/).

- http://shoryuken.com/2015/03/14/mortal-kombat-x-will-not-allow-cross-region-netplay/
- http://www.lazygamer.net/gamehub/mortal-kombat/psa-dont-buy-mortal-kombat-x-on-ps4-from-outside-of-your-region/

As an aside, this is probably for the best since the previous games have reported latency issues (MK9, Injustice, etc). I've heard that the latency is enough to affect combos and your timings. So, this is probably for the best even if it's annoying...

Comment: Well, the tweet says that the restriction is the same as in MK9, so it alone can't fix same problems, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Online on MKX is region locked to US or EU depending on which game you buy. It is hard coded into the game only on PS4. The xbox version of mk9 mkx and injustice has no region lock.

Comment: Do you have a source for that? And can I, having EU version, invite a US friend to play directly?